# A doubt about Theorem 22 in textbook Algebra by Saunders MacLane and Garrett Birkhoff

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, group-homomorphism

I'm reading **Theorem 22** in textbook *Algebra* by Saunders MacLane and Garrett Birkhoff.

[image]

> It follows that $\phi_*S = \phi[S] := \{\phi(x) \mid x \in S\}$ and $\phi^*T = \phi^{-1}[T] := \{x \in G \mid \phi(x) \in T\}$.

and its proof

[image]
[image]

Here is **Proposition 10**:

[image]

---

Due to the properties of the set-valued functions $\phi[\cdot], \phi^{-1}[\cdot]$ induced from $\phi (\cdot)$, we always have $\phi_{*}\left(S_{1} \cap S_{2}\right) \subseteq \phi_{*} S_{1} \cap \phi_{*} S_{2}$. One sufficient condition for the equality to hold is that $\phi$ is injective.

Could you please elaborate on how Proposition 10 lead to the equality?

Comment: To the user casting the close vote, please elaborate on how my question needs clarity.

Comment: You've asked enough interesting questions based on that book, now, that I've purchased a copy.

Comment: Hi @Shaun, your appreciation is a great source of encourage for me to study math ^^

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you saying "this is obvious, why so we need the proposition?!"

Comment: @user1729 I understand that $\phi_{*}\left(S_{1} \cap S_{2}\right) \subseteq \phi_{*} S_{1} \cap \phi_{*} S_{2}$, but not $\phi_{*} S_{1} \cap \phi_{*} S_{2} \subseteq \phi_{*}\left(S_{1} \cap S_{2}\right)$. And I don't know how Prop 10 helps us have the latter inclusion.

Comment: @LAD Oh, right. For this direction you need to understand and use the kernel. In particular, for arbitrary subgroups $S\leq G$ we have $\phi^{-1}(\phi(S))=S\ker\phi$, and here the kernel is contained in what you will use for $S$, and therefore that S\ker(\phi)=S$. (Sorry, don't have time to flesh out the details.)

Comment: Thank you @user1729! Just "understand and use the kernel" is enough.

Comment: Okay, great. Do you want me to give that as a "hint" answer, or would you rather wait for a full one?

Comment: (actually, you should type up the answer yourself!)

Comment: @user1729 I've proved it with my approach. I'm trying to prove it with your approach, i.e. $\phi^{-1}[\phi[S]]= S \operatorname{ker} \phi $. Then I will post it as an answer.

Comment: @user1729 Although I'm able to prove $\phi^{-1}[\phi[S]] = S \operatorname{ker} \phi = S$, I don't see how to infer $\phi [S_{1}] \cap \phi [S_{2}] \subseteq \phi [S_{1} \cap S_{2}]$. Could you please have a look at my below answer and leave me some hints to proceed?

Comment: I think the thing you are missing is the following: If $H\leq \phi(S_1)$ then $\phi^{-1}(H)\leq S_1$ (this uses the fact that $S_1$ contains the kernel), and similarly for $S_2$. So then $\phi^{-1}(H)\leq S_1\cap S_2$, and apply $\phi$ to both sides. I think maybe the point of the proposition is that this allows you to consider subgroups $H$?

Comment: @user1729 Do you mean the following argument? We have $\phi [S_{1}] \cap \phi [S_{2}] \subseteq \phi [S_{1}]$ and thus $\phi^{-1}[\phi [S_{1}] \cap \phi [S_{2}]] \subseteq \phi^{-1}[\phi [S_{1}]] \color{red}{=} S_1$. Similarly, $\phi^{-1}[\phi [S_{1}] \cap \phi [S_{2}]] \subseteq S_2$. Hence $\phi^{-1}[\phi [S_{1}] \cap \phi [S_{2}]] \subseteq S_1 \cap S_2$ and thus $\phi [S_{1}] \cap \phi [S_{2}] \subseteq \phi[S_1 \cap S_2]$. Do you feel that my posted answer is fine or contains logical mistakes?

Comment: Yes, that argument works and was what I was aiming for before (I was wondering how my previous hint fitted in - I'm glad you figured out my logic!). However, I am still unsure how the proposition fits in (I cannot see where it is used here, as in what you have written you did not consider subgroups).

Comment: @user1729 I guess the proposition is to ensure "each of these sets of subgroups is closed under intersection".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, $\phi [S_{1} \cap S_{2}] \subseteq \phi [S_{1}] \cap \phi [S_{2}]$. Below is my use of kernel to obtain $\phi [S_{1}] \cap \phi [S_{2}] \subseteq \phi [S_{1} \cap S_{2}]$:

> For $y \in \phi[S_1] \cap \phi[S_2]$, $y=\phi(x_1)=\phi(x_2)$ for some $x_1 \in S_1, x_2 \in S_2$. Then $\phi(x_1 x_2^{-1}) = \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2)^{-1} =1$. Hence $x_1 x_2^{-1} \in \operatorname{ker} \phi \subseteq S_1 \cap S_2$ and thus $x_1 x_2^{-1} \in S_1$. Because $S_1$ is a subgroup, $x_2 \in S_1$. Hence $x_2 \in S_1 \cap S_2$. The result then follows.

---

Here is a lemma suggested by @user1729.

> *Lemma:* If $\phi:G \to H$ is morphism of groups and $S$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $\phi^{-1}[\phi[S]] = S \operatorname{ker} \phi = S$.

*Proof:* Notice that $\phi^{-1}[\phi[S]] = \{x \in G \mid \exists y\in S: \phi(x) = \phi (y)\} \overset{(\star)}{=} \{x \in G \mid \exists y\in S: xy^{-1} \in \operatorname{ker} \phi\}$. It follows that $\phi^{-1}[\phi[S]] = S \operatorname{ker} \phi$. Notice that $S \subseteq\phi^{-1}[\phi[S]]$. With similar reasoning in my above approach, we get $(x,y) \in S \times G$ and $\phi(x) = \phi(y)$ implies $y \in S$. Hence $\phi^{-1}[\phi[S]] = S$.

$(\star)$: This is because $\phi$ is a morphism of groups.

Then we use this lemma to obtain the latter inclusion as follows:

We have $\phi [S_{1}] \cap \phi [S_{2}] \subseteq \phi [S_{1}]$ and thus $\phi^{-1}[\phi [S_{1}] \cap \phi [S_{2}]] \subseteq \phi^{-1}[\phi [S_{1}]] \color{red}{=} S_1$. Similarly, $\phi^{-1}[\phi [S_{1}] \cap \phi [S_{2}]] \subseteq S_2$. Hence $\phi^{-1}[\phi [S_{1}] \cap \phi [S_{2}]] \subseteq S_1 \cap S_2$ and thus $\phi [S_{1}] \cap \phi [S_{2}] \subseteq \phi[S_1 \cap S_2]$.